# Problem with Nullable field in Linq stored procedure + crystal reports on VS2008

Tags: sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a table in Sql Server that contain an int field **price** that **allow nulls**. 
I have created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_test]
AS
    select a.id, a.product, case when a.price is null then 0 else a.price end
    from tblOne a
    ...
```

I have also created a **linq to sql** file that uses **proc_test**.

The problem is that auto generated linq to sql code in: **designer.cs** has a **nullable price** variable and **Crystal Reports** dosen't allow nullable variables.

PS: I'm not allowed to change the structure of ***tblOne***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IsNull() function instead of the case expression. Therefore change your stored procedure to be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_test]
AS
    select a.id, a.product, isnull(a.price, 0)
    from tblOne a
    ...
```

Note:

Coalesce is not suitable in this situation:

> An expression involving ISNULL with non-null parameters is considered
>   to be NOT NULL, while expressions involving COALESCE with non-null
>   parameters is considered to be NULL. In SQL Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Hey, @PhamMinh: if this works for you, click the check mark next to the answer to accept it, and vote it up if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually change the mapping in the linq to sql file so that it is not null. The SP will never return null anyway. The file is a dbml right?

I don't even know if thats possible. I know it would if it were linq to entities.

Comment: I modified the auto generate file, but when delete or add or anything else to change, it will refresh and reload again.